# Issue doing a basic option menu system - Aways getting the message "Option not available"

Tags: python

Im showing some text options associated to numbers and then I want to execute some functions based on number that user enter.

First user need to choose 1 or 2, when user choose 1 it is working fine.

But when user choose 2 then I ask user to select other option, and when user choose any number it is always showing option not available.

But I just want to show this message when user choose a number that isnt 3,4,5 or 7.

Do you see where the issue is and how to fix this logic?

```
def nav(number):
    while True:
        input = raw_input(number)
        if input == "1":
            upload()
            return False
        elif input == "2":
            results = table.get()
            # here I show the name of users from database
            for r in results:
                print r["name"]
            print " 3 - Add user"
            print " 4 - Edit user"
            print " 5 - Remove user"
            print " 7 - Exit"
            nav("Select an option: ")

            if input == "":
                print "field is empty"
            if input == "3":
                addUser()
                return False
            if input == "4":
                removeUser()
            if input== "5":
                editUser()
        elif input== "7":
                return False
        else:
            print "Option not available"

def main():
    print " 1 - Users managment"
    print " 2 - Upload Files"
    print " 7 - Exit"
    nav("Select an option: ")

main()
```

Comment: Sorry, I update the code with nav().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two functions. One that asks you to choose an option and one that parses that choice. For instance:

```
def upload():
    # does whatever upload does....

def user_mgmt():
    def adduser():
        """Adds a new user"""
        pass
    def edituser():
        """Edits an existing user"""
        pass
    def deluser():
        """Deletes an existing user"""
        pass
    response_options = {'3': ('add user', adduser),
                        '4': ('edit user', edituser),
                        '5': ('remove user', deluser),
                        '7': ('exit', sys.exit)}
    response_func = make_choice(response_options)
    response_func()

def nav():
    response_options = {'1': ('manage users', user_mgmt),
                        '2': ('upload', upload),
                        '7': ('exit', sys.exit)}
    response_func = make_choice(response_options)
    response_func()

def make_choice(optiontable):
    for resp, msg_func in optiontable.items():
        msg, _ = msg_func
        print("{} - {}".format(resp, msg))
    usr_resp = raw_input(">> ")
    try:
        result = optiontable[usr_resp][1]
    except KeyError:
        raise  # let the caller handle it
    return result
```

This is actually a pretty good use case for a `collections.namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple

Choice = namedtuple("Choice", ['msg', 'callback'])

def nav():
    response_options = {'1': Choice(msg="Add user", callback=adduser),
                        ...}
    result = make_choice(response_options)
    if result is None:
        # improper user input -- handle it
    else:
        result.callback()

def make_choice(optiontable):
    for resp, choiceobj in optiontable.items():
        print("{} - {}".format(resp, choiceobj.msg))
    usr_resp = raw_input(">> ")
    return optiontable.get(usr_resp, None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both solutions. It is working perfectly!